# Trigger blocks the INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a html form that send some data in a database. I just created a trigger that on every people that complete the *city* field with *LA* will add the word "HI FROM LA" in a column named *tag*.

The problem is that after I created this trigger I get an error when I try to submit a form:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

The trigger is:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER update_tag BEFORE INSERT ON users
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (NEW.city= 'LA') THEN
            INSERT INTO users
            SET NEW.tag = 'HI FROM LA';
            END IF;
        END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

The insert is done with:

```
INSERT INTO users(id, name, city) VALUES(23, "John", "LA")
```

What alternatives do I have to avoid this conflict?

EDITED TRIGGER:

I also created a new table called 'trigger':

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER update_tag BEFORE INSERT ON users
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (NEW.city= 'LA') THEN
            INSERT INTO trigger
            SET NEW.tag = 'HI FROM LA';
            END IF;
        END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

With this trigger, I get an error on line 5

Comment: the INSERT in the trigger... how can that work? Check it. Do you want to UPDATE or INSERT? What "users" row do you want to modify? Shouldn't  it be an UPDATE users... WHERE...?

Comment: I'm curious to see what a good SQL developer will say.  Seems like you can't / wouldn't be able to trigger an update on the record you are creating.  One workaround would to be to store tags in a separate table.

Comment: What you are doing is INSERTING in a table that will trigger an INSERT on the same table. Thus creating an endless loop.

Comment: You can't do operation on the same table with trigger where u have done some insert or update and as @cale_b mentioned you need to use a secondary table to store the tags.

Comment: @nl-x, yup. I saw that. Can you suggest me any alternative to keep the trigger and to avoid that problem? abhik, got it. I will try it right now. Thank you.

Comment: @nl-x, I know that the main ideea of what I'm doing there is silly and useles, but I do it just to learn a few about trigges.

Comment: @user140102 see my answer for an alternative. But using triggers in this context is not advised. You primarily use triggers to do stuff with OTHER tables, than the ones that triggered the trigger.

Comment: @nl-x, ok, practically, using a trigger in this context is a bad practice. Got it. I still want to see it working just for knowing that I'm able to create a trigger. After that I will delete it and user the option writed by you bellow, that I admit that seems to be more inteligent. I just edited my first post. Please have a look.

Comment: @user140102 You CANNOT do it in the context where you want the trigger to do stuff to the table that triggered the trigger.

Comment: I created another table with a column called tag. So, when I do the insert in `users` I want the trigger to put me that string in `trigger` table

Comment: @user140102 In that case use the trigger you had above, but change `INSERT INTO trigger` into `INSERT INTO other_table_name`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to work with triggers for this.

The trigger you have showed us would even create an endless loop, if it were to work.

Just use your insert query like this:
`insert into users set (city, tag) values ('LA', concat('HI FROM ', city));`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use an AFTER INSERT trigger to handle this. 
Let the insert take place, then check the value of which was inserted in to the city column. If it meets your criteria then you can perform an UPDATE on the that row.

Does this help?

Comment: Ah, i see. Sorry I've not worked with that. I know this is possible in SQL Server. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When in a before trigger, the NEW record is the record that is to be inserted. Just change whatever field(s) you want and that change will go into the table as part of the normal insert. No need to execute a separate update.

```
        IF (NEW.city= 'LA') THEN
        SET NEW.tag = 'HI FROM LA';
        END IF;
```

The trigger ends, the row (with the value of the TAG field possibly altered) is inserted.